# How do you test an AJAX request with RSpec/RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, testing, rspec, mocha.js

I'm fairly new to RoR and recently started learning BDD/Rspec for testing my application.  I've been looking for a way to spec an AJAX request, but so far I haven't found much documentation on this at all.

Anyone know how to do this?  I'm using rails 2.3.8, rspec 1.3.0 and mocha 0.9.8 for my stubs (which I'm also in the process of  learning...)

Answer (score 111):

If you're talking about testing it inside your controller specs, where you normally call

```
get :index
```

to make an HTTP request to the index action, you would instead call

```
xhr :get, :index
```

to make an XmlHttpRequest (AJAX) request to the index action using GET.

Comment: Awesome!  This is what worked for me.  `xhr :put, :update, :format => "js"`

Comment: @BeMathis can't be sure what's on the controller side of things.. If he is using something like `respond_to { |format| format.js }` to render then you'd most definitely need the `format: "js"` or you'd receive a `ActionController::UnknownFormat` error

Comment: Format: 'json' was what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 47):

### Rails 5 / 6

Since Rails 5.0 (with RSpec 3.X), try setting `xhr: true` like this:

```
get :index, xhr: true
```

### Background

Here's the relevant code in the [ActionController::TestCase](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/843345cae59b73e50af685ac1303a419a06b4c91/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L500-L505). Setting the `xhr` flag ends up adding the following headers:

```
if xhr
  @request.set_header "HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH", "XMLHttpRequest"
  @request.fetch_header("HTTP_ACCEPT") do |k|
    @request.set_header k, [Mime[:js], Mime[:html], Mime[:xml], "text/xml", "*/*"].join(", ")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9):

Syntax changed a bit for Rails 5 and rspec > 3.1(i believe)

for POST requests:

```
post :create, xhr: true, params: { polls: { question: 'some' } }
```

you now need explicitely set `params`

for GET requests:

```
get :action, xhr: true, params: { id: 10 }
```

for rails 4 and rspec <= 3.1

```
xhr post :create, { polls: { question: 'some' } }
```

GET requests:

```
xhr get :show, id: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example:

```
get "/events", xhr: true, params: { direction: "past" }
```