# How to write a remote request spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-6

I've got an action in my rails app that responds both in html and js format.
The result, according to the format, changes a bit. So I'd like to write one test for html and other for js response.
I'm using rspec.

Controller:

```rb
# app/controllers/my_controller.rb
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def my_action
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        # Do something...
      end

      format.js do
        # Do something else...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Spec:

```rb
# spec/requests/my_spec.rb
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "My", type: :request do
  describe "GET /my_action" do
    context 'HTML' do
      # HTML tests
    end

    context 'JS' do
      # JS tests
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, that is how you do it.  I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to trigger a js request in rspec.

Comment: End the URL with `.js`

Comment: It must be something like `get my_action_path, format: :js`

Comment: I got this error      `ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest:
       Security warning: an embedded <script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to permit cross-origin JavaScript embedding.`

Comment: You're looking for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44680041/1930295

Comment: Yes. It's the same question with different words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails detects request format via http `Accept` header, in tests there's a helper for simulating xhr (also sets `X-Requested-With`, which is part of CSRF mitigation):

```rb
get "/some/path/to/my_action", xhr: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try all the possible combinations of this:

```rb
put :update, params.merge(format: :js), xhr: true, format: :js, headers: { 'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'text/javascript' }
```

and then remove one of the parameters to test to find the final one.